# Calculate $3$ sides of any triangles from $S,P,R$ and $r$.

Tags: triangles, area

Is there any way to calculate $3$ sides of any triangles $(a,b,c)$, If we know Area $S$, Perimeter $P$, Circumradius $R$ and inradius $r$.

I took a deep look in to Wikipedia page, but no clue:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inradius $r=\dfrac{S}{P/2}$
so this information is useless

$R=\dfrac{a b c }{4S}$

Let $p=P/2$ by Heron formula

$p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)=S^2$

which leads to

$\begin{cases}   a+b+c=P \\ abc=4RS \\(b+c-a) (a + b - c) (a - b + c) (a + b + c)=16S^2\\\end{cases}$

Then solve the $12$th degree system and you are done!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The three values,
semiperimeter $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$,
inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$ 
define a cubic equation,

\begin{align} 
x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=0
,
\end{align}

which roots are the values of the three sides $a,b,c$ of the triangle:

the coefficients are
\begin{align} 
a_2&=-(a+b+c)=-2\rho
,\\
a_1&=ab+bc+ca=\rho^2+4rR+r^2
,\\
a_0&=-abc=-4r\rho R
.
\end{align}

**Edit:**

---

Some light on how the expression for 
$a_1=ab+bc+ca$ in terms of $\rho, r$ and $R$
can be derived.

From Heron's formula for the area $S$ of triangle
we have:
\begin{align}
&\rho^4-(a+b+c)\rho^3+(ab+bc+ca)\rho^2-abc \rho -S^2=0
,\\
&\rho^4-2\rho\rho^3+(ab+bc+ca)\rho^2-abc \rho -S^2=0
,\\
&-\rho^4+(ab+bc+ca)\rho^2-abc \rho -S^2=0
,\\
a_1&=
ab+bc+ca
=
\rho^2+abc \rho^{-1} +S^2\rho^{-2}
.
\end{align}

Now, using well-known identities $S=\rho\,r$
and $R=\frac{abc}{4S}=\frac{abc}{4\rho\,r}$, we obtain the final result:

\begin{align}
a_1=
ab+bc+ca
&=
\rho^2+abc \rho^{-1} +S^2\rho^{-2}
\\
&=
\rho^2+4\,\rho\,r\,R \rho^{-1} +(\rho\,r)^2\rho^{-2}
\\
&=
\rho^2+4r\,R +r^2
.
\end{align}

---

In fact, more cubics can be constructed to solve the triangle,
based on this known triple $\rho,r,R$
of linear measures. 
The cubic for 
$\cot\tfrac\alpha2,\cot\tfrac\beta2,\cot\tfrac\gamma2$
is the most beautiful and symmetric:

\begin{align}
 a_0&=a_2=
 -\frac{\rho}{r}
 ,\\
 a_1&=
 \frac{4R}{r}+1
 ,\\
 y^3&-\frac{\rho}{r} y^2
 + \left(\frac{4R}{r}+1\right)y
 -\frac{\rho}{r}
 =0.
\end{align}

Comment: @Raffaele: Thanks. Of course, $4RS=4R\,r\rho$. 
It just somehow looks nicer to use the three input measures
of the same dimension (linear).
Also, $\rho,r,R$
can be equivalently replaced with 
$\rho,S,d=a\,b\,c$ 
with dimensions of 
length, area and volume.

Comment: @g.kov Thank you, Nice trick! BTW, If you have time, would you mind to tell me how do you know the equation x^3 + a2x^2+a1x + a0 = 0 ? And the formula of a1, a2, a3 ? I'm really curious about that.

Comment: @IncptMobis: If we have two unknowns, say, $a,b$
and their sum $p$ and their product $q$ is known,
then the roots of quadratic equations $x^2-px+q=0$
are the values of $a,b$. Similarly,
for 3 unknowns $a,b,c$, 
if we know their sum $u$,
their product $w$ 
and the sum of their pairwise products,
$v=ab+bc+ca$, then 
roots of the cubic equation $x^3-ux^2+vx-w$
provide the answer.
Hint: expand $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$.

Comment: @IncptMobis:  See added explaination for $a_1$.