# There is no such polygon whose perimeter is equal to the difference between the circumferences of its circumscribed and inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

This is a slight variation of my previous

[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579805/no-polygon-has-the-same-area-as-the-difference-between-its-inscribed-and-circums).
There I questioned regarding the area of a polygon, here I am wondering about the perimeter of any polygon.

So my hypothesis is as follows:

> There is no such polygon whose perimeter is equal to the difference between the circumferences of its circumscribed and inscribed circle.
>   The inscribed circle **must** touch **all** edges and the circumscribed circle **must** pass through **all** vertices.

Can anyone verify my hypothesis or find a counter-proof? I have tried some regular polygons and some common triangles and it has held so far.
I have mainly put this question to check that it holds for regular polygons but I believe that it should also hold for irregular polygons (just gut feeling, could be false). I would appreciate any help that I can receive. Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:**
As it has been proven to not hold for all polygons, I want to ask the following questions:
Are there finitely many irregular polygons that **obey** this hypothesis?
Are there finitely many irregular polygons that **disobey** this hypothesis?
Does this hold for regular polygons?
I would appreciate answers to these questions and I would like to thank Alex for his answer. All the best!

Comment: Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I hope what you're finding from these questions is that gut feeling is not enough reason to believe something in mathematics!

Comment: True that! But _sometimes_, as in the case of Einstein's Cosmological constant, it _may_ just work out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such a triangle satisfying the given condition.

Denote $\displaystyle c = \left(\frac{π + 1}{2π - 1}\right)^2$, then it can be verified that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} < c <1$. Also denote $\displaystyle x_0 = \frac{c + \sqrt{2c - 1}}{1 - c}$, then $(1 - c)x_0^2 - 2cx_0 + (1 - c) = 0$, which implies $x_0^2 + 1 = c(x_0 + 1)^2$.

Now, take a right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $BC = 1$, $CA = x_0$, $AB = \sqrt{1 + x_0^2} = \sqrt{c} (x_0 + 1)$. The inradius and the circumradius of $\triangle ABC$ are\begin{gather*}
r = \frac{1}{2} (BC + CA - AB) = \frac{1}{2} (1 + x_0 - \sqrt{1 + x_0^2}) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{c}}{2}(x_0 + 1),\\
R = \frac{1}{2} AB = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 + x_0^2} = \frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}(x_0 + 1),
\end{gather*}
respectively. Note that $(2\sqrt{c} - 1) π = \sqrt{c} + 1$, therefore,\begin{align*}
2πR - 2πr &= π(2 \sqrt{c} - 1)(x_0 + 1) = (\sqrt{c} + 1)(x_0 + 1) = BC + CA + AB.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

A numeric example of suitable isosceles triangle:

[image]

\begin{align} 
R&=1
,\\
\alpha&\approx 18.5528612^\circ
,\quad
\beta=\gamma \approx  80.7235694^\circ
,\\
a&\approx 0.6363589
,\quad
b=c\approx 1.9738442
,\\
r&\approx 0.2704262
,\\
a+b+b&\approx 4.5840473
,\\
2\pi(R-r)&\approx 4.5840473
.
\end{align}

**Edit:**

Another example is an obtuse isosceles triangle:

[image]

\begin{align} 
R&=1
,\\
\alpha&\approx 106.8724079^\circ
,\quad
\beta=\gamma \approx  36.56379605^\circ
,\\
a&\approx 1.9139069
,\quad
b=c\approx 1.1914349
,\\
r&\approx 0.3161467
,\\
a+b+b&\approx 4.2967768
,\\
2\pi(R-r)&\approx 4.2967768
.
\end{align}

**Edit:**

And these are the only two suitable shapes of isosceles triangles.
This can be shown as follows.

Using known identities for triangles

\begin{align} 
\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma&=\frac{a+b+c}{2R}
,\\
\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma&=\frac{r}{R}+1
.
\end{align}

For isosceles triangle we have

\begin{align} 
\sin2\beta+2\sin\beta&=\frac{a+b+c}{2R}
,\\
-\cos2\beta+2\cos\beta&=\frac{r}{R}+1
,\\
\end{align}

and condition $a+b+c=2\pi(R-r)$ 
can be expressed in terms of $\beta$ as follows:

\begin{align}
2\sin\beta\cos\beta+2\sin\beta - 
\pi(1+2\cos^2\beta-2\cos\beta)=0
,
\end{align}

which can be simplified to

\begin{align}
5\pi t^4-2\pi t^2-8t+\pi&=0
,\qquad t=\tan\tfrac\beta2
.
\end{align}

For $\beta\in(0,\tfrac\pi2)$,
this equation results in two real values
$t_1\approx 0.3303679220$,
$t_2\approx 0.8499172732$
with corresponding values of $\beta$,
shown above.

---

**Edit:**
Using that the sides $a,b,c$ of a triangle
with semiperimeter $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$,
incircle $r$ and circumcircle $R$ 
[are the roots of cubic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2542640/122782)

\begin{align}
x^3&-2\rho x^2+(\rho^2+4rR+r^2)x-4\rho rR
\tag{g1}\label{g1}
\end{align}

and scaling the triangle such that $R=1$,
the condition $2\rho=2\pi(R-r)$ converts \eqref{g1} to

\begin{align}
x^3-2\pi\,(1-r)\,x^2+((\pi^2+1)\,r^2+(4-2\pi^2)\,r+\pi^2)\,x-4\pi\,r(1-r)
\tag{g2}\label{g2}
.
\end{align}

Recall that the cubic polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has discriminant
\begin{align} 
\Delta&=b^2c^2-27 a^2 d^2-4(a c^3+b^3 d)+18 abcd
,\\
\text{and in case of \eqref{g2}}\quad
\Delta=
&-(\pi^2+1)^2\,r^4
\\
&+4\,(\pi^4+6\,\pi^2-3)\,r^3
\\
&-2\,(19\,\pi^2+3\,\pi^4+24)\,r^2
\\
&+4\,(\pi^4+3\,\pi^2-16)\, r
\\
&-\pi^2(\pi^2-4)
\tag{g3}\label{g3}
,\\
\Delta&>0\quad \forall\ r\in(0.2704262, 0.3161467)
,  
\end{align}

that means, there are infinitely many scalene triangles,
which inradius is in this range,
as well as there also are infinitely many triangles
with $r\in(0,0.2704262)\cup(0.3161467,0.5)$
for which the condition $2\rho=2\pi(R-r)$ does not hold.

For example, let's take $r=0.29$.
Solutions to
\begin{align}
\\
\text{gives }\quad&
a\approx 0.7586625863,\quad b\approx 1.722967032,\quad c\approx 1.979431950
,\\
a+b+c&\approx 4.461061568
,\\
2\pi(R-r)&\approx 4.461061568
.
\end{align}

[image]

Also note that the two endpoints of the $r$-interval 
correspond to the pair of isosceles triangles shown above.